# Cordova Plugin: Send event to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to develop a Cordova plugin for Android following the tutorial found here: http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-creating-a-cordova-phonegap-plugin-for-android-app/

So far, so good. However, I'd like to know how to send data/trigger an event in my Javascript code from my plugin - for example, when a user taps an icon in my native code, I'd like my javascript to do something. Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I got it to work as follows:

I created a private CallbackContext object in my plugin:

```
private CallbackContext callbackContext;
```

and stored the CallbackContext supplied in the execute() method in it:

```
public boolean execute(final String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
}
```

Elsewhere in my Java code, I can access this callback and send plugin results to it. This callback will become invalid, however, after it's first triggered, unless keepCallback is set to `true`:

```
PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "WHAT");
pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
```

This made me a happy camper. I hope it helps someone else!

Comment: Fortunately the functionality I was building was already provided by the iOS plugins.

Comment: May I know how does the iOS plugin that you used send event to JS?

Comment: can you call a javascript function with the pluginResult ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can trigger webview from Native code.

**For Android :**

> this.appView.loadUrl("javascript:yourmethodname());");

**For iOS :**

> [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"yourmethodname()"];

**`yourmethodname`** should be the javascript function you wish to call.

Comment: This only works if calling from the CordovaActivity, the question requires calling it from a plugin.

Comment: what libraries are you importing to get this to work from a plugin?

Comment: @nomaam this is android webview

Answer (score 2):

Using Android I achieved it with:

```java
cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> webView.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('hey!');"));
```

Comment: what libraries are you importing for this to work? I get a compilation error on "cordova." and "webView." cannot find symbol for both. i am running this from a plugin

Comment: The java file should be in `/src/android/`, then make sure that `/plugin.xml` is properly configured. I'd recommend to start with a plugin boilerplate.